# Receiving an variable is not defined (Uncaught ReferenceError) when variable is clearly assigned in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm receiving an Uncaught ReferenceError on a variable I assign in function that runs on a onblur event. Says the variable is undefined, when it is clearly defined in the function.

Error Message:

Uncaught ReferenceError:

```
labSectionsByGraduate is not defined
    at calculateGTALabCost (AvailableFundsCosts.aspx:218)
    at doCalculations (AvailableFundsCosts.aspx:269)
    at HTMLInputElement.onblur (AvailableFundsCosts.aspx:685)
```

I tried add `alert(labSectionsByGraduate)` to test what was going on just after the 3rd variable(`GTASemesterStipend`) and that works been when I use an `alert(GTALabCost)` nothing happens for the alert. I guessing it has something to do with my `if` conditions.

```
function calculateGTALabCost()
        {
            var labSectionsbyGraduate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cphMain_gridPTA_iTxtAmount_0").value);
            var GTAlab = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cphMain_gridTLS_iTxtAmount_1").value);
            var GTASemesterStipend = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cphMain_gridTLS_iTxtAmount_5").value);

            if(isNaN(labSectionsbyGraduate))
            {labSectionsbyGraduate = 0.00;}
            if(isNaN(GTAlab))
            {GTAlab = 0.00;}
            if(isNaN(GTASemesterStipend))
            {GTASemesterStipend = 0.00;}

            var GTALabCost = parseFloat((labSectionsByGraduate / GTAlab) * GTASemesterStipend);

            alert(GTALabCost);

            var cell = document.getElementById("cphMain_gridPC").rows[2].cells;

            cell[1].innerHTML = GTALabCost.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });

        }
```

I expect the output to change the cell of my table/grid to answer of the calculation that am trying to do.

Comment: *Exactly* what is the error message? (The whole message)

Comment: Also note that if `GTAlab` is initialized to zero, that division operation will give `Infinity`.

Comment: could it be some with parseFloat ... value ?

Comment: There's no reason to use `parseFloat()` on the results of an expression involving numbers; it's already a float.

Comment: You simply have a typo: ```labSectionsbyGraduate``` is not same as ```labSectionsByGraduate``` ...

Comment: Thanks Mischa, I guess it's good to have another set of eyes, it was the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line `var GTALabCost = parseFloat((labSectionsByGraduate / GTAlab) * GTASemesterStipend);` uses `labSectionsByGraduate` but you define `labSectionsbyGraduate`. Just a camel case error. Cheers!